# Why the value of getBase getBaseline() of Line RelativeLayout contained a TextView is -1?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff00ff"
    tools:context=".performence.Main6Activity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_relative_layout"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="200px"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/child_text"
                android:text="text1"
                android:layout_width="50px"
                android:layout_height="50px" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/child_relative_layout"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="400px"
            android:layout_marginStart="400px"
            android:background="#ff00"
            android:text="000002222" />



        <Button
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

onCreate():

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           System.out.println("parent baseLine=" + ((RelativeLayout)v.getParent()).getBaseline());
           System.out.println("child  baseLine=" + findViewById(R.id.child_relative_layout).getBaseline());
       }
   });
```

log:

```
System.out: parent baseLine=45
System.out: child  baseLine=-1
```

My question is why the parent RelativeLayout got the baseLine value 45 while child RelativeLayout got the baseLine value -1?

Snippet in RelativeLayout onMeasure() method:

```
// Use the top-start-most laid out view as the baseline. RTL offsets are
        // applied later, so we can use the left-most edge as the starting edge.
        View baselineView = null;
        LayoutParams baselineParams = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = views[i];
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                final LayoutParams childParams = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                if (baselineView == null || baselineParams == null
                        || compareLayoutPosition(childParams, baselineParams) < 0) {
                    baselineView = child;
                    baselineParams = childParams;
                }
            }
        }
        mBaselineView = baselineView;
```

According to the snippet,if RelativeLayout contain one view and this view will become baselineView.

Also i have set breakpoint right after onMeasure() method of child Relativelayout：
[image]

First,mSortedVerticalChildren contains the child_text(TextView) .So mBaselineView will reference to child_text after snippet above.But the  value of mBaselineView is null!It really confusing me.